# Evaluate this limit

Tags: calculus

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{(n+1)^x +(n+2)^x +....+(2n)^x -n }{x}$$
I tried L'Hospital's Rule, I got
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(n+1)^x ln(n+1) +(n+2)^x ln(n+2)  +...+(2n)^x ln(2n)  }{1}$$
$$=ln(n+1) +ln(n+2) +.....+ln(2n)$$ 
$$=ln\left((n+1)(n+2)(n+3)....(2n)\right)$$
but I could not evaluate neither the sum nor the product
I want to know how can I evaluate the sum or the product and get a solution without using L'Hospital's Rule if it exists

Comment: you can apply Riemann sum

Comment: the result should be $$-\text{log$\Gamma $}(n)+\text{log$\Gamma $}(2
   n)+\log (2)$$

Comment: what is the procedure ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have found a different result. The function is $$\frac{\sum _{k=n}^{2 n} (k+1)^x-n}{x}=\frac{\zeta (-x,n+1)-\zeta (-x,2 n+2)-n}{x}$$ apply l'Hopital rule and plug $x\to 0$ I got $$\log \frac{(2 n)!}{(n-1)!}+\log\frac{2 n+1}{n}$$

Comment: Your answer is correct and it can't be simplified further. To avoid L'Hospital's Rule just use the standard limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac {a^{x} - 1}{x}=\log a$.

Comment: How can i eliminate n to get use this form ? @Paramanand Singh

Comment: Why eliminate $n$? $n$ is a part of question and it will also be in the answer. The expression can be written as $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(n+i)^{x}-1}{x}$$ and hence the limit is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(n+i)=\log\prod_{i=1}^{n}(n+i)$$ same as your answer.

Comment: I am also a bit surprised at the approaches suggested in comments. We don't need Gamma and zeta and even Riemann sum to evaluate such run of the mill simple limits. The method given by the asker itself is one simple approach but it uses L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Can we prove that this result is less than  $$nln\left(\frac{3n+1}{2}\right)$$ ?